# Compare the words from a data frame and calculate a matrix with the length of the biggest word for each pair

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, distance, text-mining

I have a data frame with a number of unique words. I want to create code in R, where each word will be compared with all the words and  creates a matrix with the length of the biggest word from each pair.

To be more comprehensive lets consider the follow example.

```
test <- c("hello", "hi", "play", "kid")
```

I want to create a matrix that compares each word in the test and gives me the length of the biggest word.

For the previous example I want to take the below matrix:

```
       hello  hi play kid
 hello  5     5   5    5

  hi    5     2   4    3

 play   5     4   4    4

  kid   5     3   4    3
```

How Can I do it in R?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this:

```
outer(test, test, function(x,y) pmax(nchar(x), nchar(y)))

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    5    5    5    5
[2,]    5    2    4    3
[3,]    5    4    4    4
[4,]    5    3    4    3
```

Or even shorter, as suggested by @Ronak Shah

```
outer(nchar(test), nchar(test), pmax)
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also use `sapply`:

```
mat <- sapply(test, function(x) pmax(nchar(x), nchar(test)))
rownames(mat) <- colnames(mat)
mat
      hello hi play kid
hello     5  5    5   5
hi        5  2    4   3
play      5  4    4   4
kid       5  3    4   3
```

Comment: @zero, I will add that the `sapply` solution will not scale well as `test` gets longer. But, you can easily add row and column names to the other answers. E.g., for the `outer` solution, you can set the column and row names by doing something like this: `colnames(mat) <- rownames(mat) <- test`. Assuming you want an answer that scales well--I would accept the `outer` answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Another option with `expand.grid` can be,

```
matrix(do.call(pmax, expand.grid(nchar(test), nchar(test))), nrow = length(test))

#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    5    5    5    5
#[2,]    5    2    4    3
#[3,]    5    4    4    4
#[4,]    5    3    4    3
```